# Running a godot gdscript about an fps shooter game

Tags: godot, gdscript

i'm using this tutorial on youtube(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgMiiUSRvSM&t=1304s) to make an fps shooter game in godot and i'm quite new to it  when i tried to run the script i have an error in the weapon_manager.gd script saying, Attempt to call function 'update_weapon_ui, in base 'null instance' on a null instance

this is the screenshot of my node tree that this script is attached to
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxi4d.png)

```
extends Spatial

# All weapons in the game
var all_weapons = {}

# carrying weapons
var weapons = {}

# HUD
var hud

var current_weapon
var current_weapon_slot = "Empty"

var changing_weapon = false
var unequipped_weapon = false

var weapon_index = 0

func _ready():
    
    hud = owner.get_node("HUD")
    
    all_weapons = {
        "Unarmed" : preload("res://weapons/Unarmed.tscn"),
         'Pistol' : preload("res://weapons/Pistol.tscn"),
        "Rifle" : preload("res://weapons/Rifle.tscn")
    }
    
    weapons = {
        "Empty" : $Unarmed,
        "Primary" : $Rifle,
        "Secondary" : $Pistol
    }
    
    # Initialize references for each weapons
    for w in weapons:
        if weapons[w] != null:
            weapons[w].weapon_manager = self
            weapons[w].player = owner
            weapons[w].visible = false
    
    # Set current weapon to unarmed
    current_weapon = weapons["Empty"]
    change_weapon("Empty")
    
    # Disable process
    set_process(false)



# Process will be called when changing weapons
func _process(delta):
    
    if unequipped_weapon == false:
        if current_weapon.is_unequip_finished() == false:
            return
        
        unequipped_weapon = true
        
        current_weapon = weapons[current_weapon_slot]
        current_weapon.equip()
    
    if current_weapon.is_equip_finished() == false:
        return
    
    changing_weapon = false
    set_process(false)



func change_weapon(new_weapon_slot):
    
    if new_weapon_slot == current_weapon_slot:
        current_weapon.update_ammo() # Refresh
        return
    
    if weapons[new_weapon_slot] == null:
        return
    
    current_weapon_slot = new_weapon_slot
    changing_weapon = true
    
    weapons[current_weapon_slot].update_ammo() # Updates the weapon data on UI, as soon as we change a weapon
    update_weapon_index()
    
    # Change Weapons
    if current_weapon != null:
        unequipped_weapon = false
        current_weapon.unequip()
    
    set_process(true)




# Scroll weapon change
func update_weapon_index():
    match current_weapon_slot:
        "Empty":
            weapon_index = 0
        "Primary":
            weapon_index = 1
        "Secondary":
            weapon_index = 2

func next_weapon():
    weapon_index += 1
    
    if weapon_index >= weapons.size():
        weapon_index = 0
    
    change_weapon(weapons.keys()[weapon_index])

func previous_weapon():
    weapon_index -= 1
    
    if weapon_index < 0:
        weapon_index = weapons.size() - 1
    
    change_weapon(weapons.keys()[weapon_index])




# Update HUD
func update_hud(weapon_data):
    var weapon_slot = "1"
    
    match current_weapon_slot:
        "Empty":
            weapon_slot = "1"
        "Primary":
            weapon_slot = "2"
        "Secondary":
            weapon_slot = "3"
    
    hud.update_weapon_ui(weapon_data, weapon_slot)
```

i tried to rewatch the tutorial and see what i miss but it didn't work i don't understand why this has an error

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the node tree of the scene that this script is attached to. It seems like `hud` is `null`; you should have gotten an error on `owner.get_node("HUD")` in that case as well.

Comment: i added a screenshot of my nodetree and there is a node called HUD in the node tree so how should i fix this problem?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `hud` is `null`, which means that the following line failed:

```
hud = owner.get_node("HUD")
```

*You should also get an error about that.*

That failed because isn't a node called `HUD` **as direct child of the root of the edited scene** that has the node that the shown script attached.

To clarify, `owner` is the root of the edited scene (`Player` in this case). And `get_node("HUD")` is looking for a **direct child** with the `name` property set to `"HUD"`.

I'll give you three solution from more efficient to less efficient.

---

The first solution is to move `HUD` so it is a direct child of `Player`. Then the following line should work:

```
hud = owner.get_node("HUD")
```

A variant of this would be to use the fixed path for the current location of `HUD` instead of moving `HUD`. Then you need this code:

```
hud = owner.get_node("Camroot/HUD")
```

Notice that the parameter of `get_node` is the path to get to the node you want in the scene tree.

---

The second solution is to use Scene Unique Nodes. To do that open the context menu on `HUD` on Scene, and select "% Access as Unique Name". That will allow you to get it like this:

```
hud = owner.get_node("%HUD")
```

---

Yet another option is to export a `NodePath`:

```
export var hud_path:NodePath
```

Which you can set to the correct node in the inspector. And then you do this to retrieve it:

```
hud = owner.get_node(hud_path)
```

---

A wildly different approach to do this is by adding the `HUD` to a node group, which you can do in the Node panel Groups tab. For example if it is in the `"hub"` you could do this:

```
hud = get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("hub")[0]
```

Notice that this is not limited to the currently edited scene, and also that it `get_nodes_in_group` gives us an array and with `[0]` I'm getting the first element (assuming there is one). A more proper usage would get the array and check if it is empty.

*As you can imagine, node groups work better if you are interested in a, well... group of nodes, instead of a single one.*

---

The third solution is to use `find_node`:

```
hud = owner.find_node("%HUD")
```

Then it will iterate over all the nodes in the scene until it finds one called `"HUD"`.

Comment: thanks for the solution it finally worked now :)